# Selected Item of Multiple Lists

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a group class which contains a list of items and a header:

```
public class MyGroup {     
    public MyGroup(string _header){
        header = _header;
    }

    protected string header = "";
    public string Header
    {
        get { return header; }
    }

    protected List<MyGroupItem> item = new List<MyGroupItem>();
    public List<MyGroupItem> Item
    {
        get { return item; }
    }
}

public class MyGroupItem {       
    public MyGroupItem(string _name, double _multiplier){
        name = _name;
        multiplier = _multiplier;
    }

    protected double multiplier = 1.0;

    protected string name = "";
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
    }
}
```

So far so good. In my main class, I have an observable collection of groups and I populate it like this:

```
protected ObservableCollection<MyGroup> groups = new ObservableCollection<MyGroup>();
public ObservableCollection<MyGroup> Groups
{
    get { return groups; }
}

protected MyGroupItem currentItem;
public MyGroupItem CurrentItem
{
    get { return currentItem; }
    set
    {
       if (currentItem== value) return;
       currentItem= value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
    }
}

....

var GroupA = new MyGroup("Group A");
GroupA.MyGroupItem.Add("Item 1", 1.0);
Groups.Add(GroupA);

currentItem = GroupA.MyGroupItem[0];
```

All of the above simply shows how I've setup my classes and observable lists.  Now, I switch over to the xaml.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Groups}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Background="Transparent" ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyGroup}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}"></TextBlock>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyGroupItem}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.CurrentItem, ElementName=ControlRoot}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="local:MyGroupItem">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

So, basically I have a ItemControl that displays multiple lists of items.  The control should place the header for the name of the group, and then show a list view of the particular items within that group.  The layout works perfectly... however, the issue comes when I deal with the ***Selected Item***. Basically, the list view allows me to select an item within one of the multiple groups... meaning that I may have multiple items selected at any given time.  For example, lets say that I select the first item in Group A.  But, then I change my selection to the second item in Group B.  Because Group B is a separate list, it allows me to activate that item... but it doesn't deselect the item in Group A.  What I'd like is that this multi-list group to act as a single list. Is this possible?  Do I need to setup a separate ***SelectionChanged*** event? And if so, how would I go about making sure when the selection is changed that it clears the selected items from all lists and only shows the correct one that the user just selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle this in your view model classes.

If you add a property to hold the selected item of each group to the `MyGroup` class and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, you could handle the `CollectionChanged` event of the `Groups` collection in the view model class to set the `CurrentItem` property and at the same time clear the `SelectedItem` property of the other groups by setting it to `null` in this event handler.

Here is an example for you.

**MyGroup.cs:**

```
public class MyGroup : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyGroup(string _header)
    {
        header = _header;
    }

    protected string header = "";
    public string Header
    {
        get { return header; }
    }

    protected List<MyGroupItem> item = new List<MyGroupItem>();
    public List<MyGroupItem> Item
    {
        get { return item; }
    }

    private MyGroupItem _item;
    public MyGroupItem SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _item; }
        set { _item = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

**MyGroupItem.cs:**

```
public class MyGroupItem
{
    public MyGroupItem(string _name, double _multiplier)
    {
        name = _name;
        multiplier = _multiplier;
    }

    protected double multiplier = 1.0;

    protected string name = "";
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
    }
}
```

**View Model:**

```
public class Window1ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Window1ViewModel()
    {
        groups.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (object item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged
                        += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
                }
            }

            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (object item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged
                        -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
                }

            };
        };

        var GroupA = new MyGroup("Group A");
        GroupA.Item.Add(new MyGroupItem("Item 1", 1.0));
        GroupA.Item.Add(new MyGroupItem("Item 2", 1.0));
        GroupA.Item.Add(new MyGroupItem("Item 3", 1.0));
        Groups.Add(GroupA);

        var GroupB = new MyGroup("Group B");
        GroupB.Item.Add(new MyGroupItem("Item 1", 1.0));
        GroupB.Item.Add(new MyGroupItem("Item 2", 1.0));
        GroupB.Item.Add(new MyGroupItem("Item 3", 1.0));
        Groups.Add(GroupB);

        currentItem = GroupA.Item[0];
    }

    private bool _handle = true;
    private void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_handle)
            return;

        MyGroup group = sender as MyGroup;
        CurrentItem = group.SelectedItem;

        //clear the selection in the other groups:
        _handle = false;
        foreach (MyGroup g in Groups)
            if (g != group)
                g.SelectedItem = null;
        _handle = true;
    }

    protected ObservableCollection<MyGroup> groups = new ObservableCollection<MyGroup>();
    public ObservableCollection<MyGroup> Groups
    {
        get { return groups; }
    }

    protected MyGroupItem currentItem;
    public MyGroupItem CurrentItem
    {
        get { return currentItem; }
        set
        {
            if (currentItem == value) return;
            currentItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Groups}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Background="Transparent" ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyGroup}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}"></TextBlock>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Item}" 
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="local:MyGroupItem">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thanks for the thorough response!